# Should we "repost" answers from "See this" answers?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, flags

Take a look at [suggested edit #1879571](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1879571). The original post was just a link to another question's answer. I was wary of the edit as it could have been an audit, but I accepted it after reading the reason. Thankfully, it wasn't an audit, but that's off topic.

Should these kinds of edits be accepted, or should we reject them and flag the original post as "Not an Answer"?

Comment: This wasn't a "repost" of the "see this" answer. Your title is a bit misleading. However, neither can I come up with a better title right now. Maybe, someone else would edit the title to reflect the correct situation. Probably this is the reason why Mr. Disappointment answered as we should reject the edit and flag the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is specifically answered with [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1879571) in mind. The edit looks perfectly legitimate. This is how Stack Exchange works.

What happened in this case was Mr A answered the question. Thereafter Mr T came and answered the same question. Mr T's answer attracted more upvotes. However, Mr A's answer got accepted by the OP of the question.

After about 4 months, Mr A had a change of heart. He believed that Mr T's answer was far superior than his answer. So, he completely wiped out his answer and replaced his answer with the text and link to Mr T's answer. This shouldn't have been done!

The editor came across that post and edited the answer to reflect the answer originally answered by Mr A. So, the edit was perfectly legitimate and should have been accepted to give the user who suggested the edit his +2 Rep. However, I don't like the way he edited the post. He just copied the text without any links. So, I would have approved his edit. Thereafter, rolled back the edit to the most relevant revision so that the links would show up in the answer.

This isn't the case of vandalism by editor, neither a case of NAA by the answerer, nor a case of duplicate question. If I had come across such post, I would have suggested/edited the post as well.

Answer (score 5):

Even if a question isn't strictly the same but the answers are, then:

- Reject the edit
- Flag the answer as NARA
- Mark the question as duplicate

Comment: NARQ? Did you mean NARA?

Comment: Should we flag multiple times? I'm sure flagging the answer with a note on the question should suffice. (Unless your a flag weight **narcissist**)

Comment: @ColeJohnson NAA/NARA, yeah.

Comment: Invoking a mod to close a question as a duplicate is too much; just do the duty of putting in your vote.